# Do I need a comma with the preposition 'несмотря на'?

Tags: предлоги, пунктуация

Do I need a comma in these sentences?

**Несмотря на** факт абсолютной незаконности присоединения Крыма **Россией, факт** наличия неоднократных нарушений международного права со стороны Запада – ещё задолго до присоединения Крыма – по-прежнему остаётся фактом.

Факт наличия неоднократных нарушений международного права со стороны Запада – ещё задолго до присоединения Крыма – по-прежнему остаётся **фактом, несмотря на** факт абсолютной незаконности присоединения Крыма Россией.

If yes, then is it possible to explain why? After all, we don't seem to need commas with other prepositions:

**На** вершине горы он казался ещё выше.

**Сквозь** бурю мы не пойдём.

Он взял больничный **в связи с** плохим самочувствием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gramota.ru [says](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0): «Обороты «**несмотря на** + существительное» обычно выделяются знаками препинания: *Как удвоить продажи, несмотря на кризис?*»

"Phrases '**несмотря на** + noun' are usually separated with commas."

The only explanation I can think of is that the preposition **несмотря на** is formed from the verb смотреть, and the whole phrase **несмотря на** + a noun looks very much like an adverbial participial phrase, деепричастный оборот, which is always singled out with commas.